# Can't change Pulumi stack built in tags

Tags: typescript, pulumi

Hey guys I've trying to add some default tags to my Pulumi stacks but not having success so far.

I was trying to add this codeblock to my Pulumi.stack.yaml file but it seems that only pulumi related tags change with these settings, github and vcs don't.

```
config:
  pulumi:tags:
    gitHub:owner: devops
    gitHub:repo: devops/infrastructure
    pulumi:project: devops
    pulumi:runtime: nodeblabla
    vcs:kind: test
    repository: devops/test
```

Couldn't find any other way to do this, can someone help on that?